# In Amazon EC2, how do I copy a EBS volume to another user?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have created an amazon EBS volume using my amazon credentials.
My customer gave me his customer credentials so that I create for him an EC2 machinge with the disk I created attached, how do I do that?

I'm using the web console, if it matters

==================

Let me add that when I do create volume in my customer's account and put my snapshot id as snapshot I get "snapshot snap-1xyz1234" does not exist. Need I somehow tell that the snaphsot is another user's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. Look for ["Modifying Snapshot Permissions" in the official docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best way may be to start up an EC2 instance under each account, and copy it over the network.  VM->VM network traffic is pretty fast, and more importantly free.