# Make a second, independent copy of an EBS volume's data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS volume with a number of snapshots. I would like a second, distinct copy of the EBS volume so I can:

- restore a snapshot on the duplicate volume
- continue using the original data on the original volume

Note this is distinct from similar questions eg, [In Amazon EC2, how do I copy a EBS volume to another user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614372/in-amazon-ec2-how-do-i-copy-a-ebs-volume-to-another-user), which are more about changing permissions in volumes so that others can access.

How can I have **continual access to two, divergent copies of the data**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [Copying an Amazon EBS Snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html) from the official docs will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your question quite a few times and I'm not sure what you mean.

Once you've created a Snapshot that snapshot is stored in S3 and is durable. Regardless if your over-write the original volume or continue using it, the snapshot you made is good.

Any later snapshots you make are also durable.